# Understanding Julia SymbolicUtils' rules

Tags: julia

I'm trying to use Julia's SymbolicUtils package to simplify some trigonometry identities, i.e.:

```
sin(a)cos(b) + cos(a)sin(b) = sin(a + b)
sin(a)cos(b) - cos(a)sin(b) = sin(a - b)
```

I was able to create a rule that simplifies the first identity but not for the second. Following that I read some documentation and tried some simpler rules in order to understand the SymbolicUtils package a bit better. For example:

First import the package and define two syms:

```
using SymbolicUtils

@syms a b
```

Then the following works as I'd expect.

```
# note: this rule is just a dummy rule
r = @rule(~x + ~y => ":)") 
r(a + b) # -> output: ":)"
r(a - b) # -> output: ":)"
```

but as soon as i try to use `sin()` and `cos()` it does not work as I'd expect:

```
r = @rule(sin(~x) + cos(~y) => ":)") 
r(sin(a) + cos(b)) # -> output: ":)"
r(sin(a) - cos(b)) # -> output: 'nothing'
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `-1*b` can match the variable `~y`, but `-1*cos(b)` does not match `cos(~y)` since there's no way to substitute `~y` so that the two are equal. You could use these rules to simplify both identities:

```
julia> rules = [
           @rule(sin(~x)*cos(~y) + cos(~x)*sin(~y) => sin(~x + ~y)),
           @rule(sin(~x)*cos(~y) + -1*cos(~x)*sin(~y) => sin(~x - ~y))
       ]

julia> simplify(sin(a)*cos(b) + cos(a)*sin(b), RuleSet(rules))
sin(a + b)

julia> simplify(sin(a)*cos(b) - cos(a)*sin(b), RuleSet(rules))
sin(a - b)
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I just thought there might be an easier way (: